# How to call a function only when user switched on my custom step?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

How i can check if user is on my custom step?
I need to call certain function ONLY if he is on my custom step ( after shipping step, before payment ).
Now i created custom step by js-component and functions in this component are called as soon as checkout page is downloaded ( on shipping step ) but i need to perform logic only on next, custom step.

Answer (score 0):

you can add code in the js file

```
Magento_Checkout\js\view\progress-bar.js
```

in this file function **navigateTo** is there, where you can add your custom code